# How do I justify this QDA expression for $a_k, ~b_{kj} $and $c_{jkl}$?

Tags: logistic, normal-distribution, discriminant-analysis

I need to solve the equation of

$$\log\left(\frac{\operatorname{Pr}(Y=k|X=x)}{\operatorname{Pr}(Y=K|X=x)}\right)$$

$$=\log\left(\frac{\pi_k \exp\left((x-\mu_k)^T|\Sigma|^{-1}(x-\mu_k)\right)}
{\pi_K \exp\left((x-\mu_K)^T|\Sigma|^{-1}(x-\mu_K)\right)}\right)$$

to find the following constants $a_k$, $b_{kj}$ and $c_{kjl}$--

[image]

using the assumptions of quadratic discriminant analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, I was supposed to multiply and divide the original expression terms from LDA by $(n-K)/(n_k-1)$ and $(n-K)/(n_K-1)$ respectively. Please let me know if this is correct:

[image]